# double sided portrait document with landscape page

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, duplex, landscape

I have a document which is mostly portrait except for one page, near end.

The document is meant to be printed double sided. When the printer encounters this landscape page it then is unable to rectify, and the pages flip/go out of sync (ie not header/header).

I went to change orientation of the single landscape page but unable to due to content of the page. Any advice?

Comment: You generally need to insert sections breaks before and after the landscape portion.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want the header on the landscape page to be printed on a short side of the page, as it is on the portrait pages?